# How to create pagination in Django?

Tags: django, pagination

I follow this Document of djangoproject.com : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/. But it is too simple. It is only Next and Previous button.

Now I want create pagination with more features such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJz8c.jpg.

This is code:

View.py

```
def hire(request):

hire_article_list = hire_article.objects.all().order_by('-id')
#hire_article_list = hire_article.objects.order_by("-publication_date")

paginator = Paginator(hire_article_list, 2) # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    hire_article_s = paginator.page(page)

except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    hire_article_s = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.

    hire_article_s = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

#return render_to_response('hire/list.html', {"page_list": page_list})
context = {'hire_article_s': hire_article_s}
return render(request, 'hire/list.html', context)
```

list.html

```
{% for j in hire_article_s %}
    {# Each "j" is a page_list  model object. #}
    <li><a href="/hire/{{ j.slug }}-{{j.id}}">{{ j.hiring}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

```
                {% if hire_article_s.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}

                <span class="current">
                    Page {{ hire_article_s.number }} of {{ hire_article_s.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>

                {% if hire_article_s.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}

        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried making pagination with more feature.

Comment: try using django endless pagination library if this is not working

Comment: but i dont want to use djangopackage. Just python code. seem too hard for me to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need last week and found this super useful gist (https://gist.github.com/jsatt/8183993) that worked fine (though I'm not sure why it wouldn't work till I put request in the function parameters). It's a subclass of django's Paginator function. You could put this in a utility file and call it whenever you want to use Paginate with the range.

For instance, I had mine in a file called utils.py, which is in my core app.

**views.py**

```
from core.utils import paginate

def hire(request):

    hire_article_list = hire_article.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    '''
    Show 25 contacts per page, with a page range of 5, which means if you are
    on page 8, it shows links to pages 6,7,8,9,10.
    '''
    hire_article_s = paginate(request, hire_article_list, 25, 5) 

    context = {'hire_article_s': hire_article_s}
    return render(request, 'hire/list.html', context)
```

**list.html**

```
{% if hire_article_s.has_previous %}
     <a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
{% endif %}

{% for range in hire_article_s.neighbor_range %}
    {% if range == hire_article_s.number %}
       <li class="pagination__item active ">{{ range }}</li>
    {% else %}
       <li class="{% if range == hire_article_s.number %}active {% endif %}"><a href="?page={{ range }}">{{ range }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 

{% if hire_article_s.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ hire_article_s.next_page_number }}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

The above code has been edited a bit. I've added the context and the template format. Note that I'm using a loop to go through `{{ hire_article_s.neighbor_range }}` and print out the page numbers. I also do a check to highlight the current page's number. the This should work, as it's pretty much my own code with your own variable names.

Comment: Thank you, but when i tried but not work. Can you post your code to me.

Comment: @user3863069 I've updated the code with some extra clarification. If this doesn't work, you need to tell me what error you're getting.

Comment: the out put look like

Comment: previous next 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 
When i click on number, nothing happend \

Comment: It's generating the page numbers, which means it's probably just an error in the HTML markup. Could you post the generated html?

Comment: i copy as you posted above in list.html

Comment: @user3863069 No, I want the GENERATED markup. That is, on the page, as you're viewing it, got page source and paste that section. If the numbers are listing out, then the view is definitely working. Your issue is from the template, probably.

Comment: can you see it on my computer via temviewer. ID: 221 724 580 pass 1100 Plz help me. You are honest. :)

Comment: I don't have teamviewer. It really would be easier if you just copy and paste   what I'm asking for...

Comment: @user3863069 You're welcome. Don't forget to hit the check mark to accept the answer as well! :)