# How do I auto generate slug using Django models

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

I have a problem with slug in forms.
I created forms from models.

here is the *models.py*

```
class hire_article(models.Model):
hiring = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
```

This is the form

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import datetime
from .models import hire_article
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class postform(ModelForm):

    # class hire_articleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("hiring",)}
    class Meta:
        # more_infomation = MyFormField(max_length=200, required=False,
        #                    help_text="Use puns liberally")
        model = hire_article
        # exclude = ['slug']
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is *admin.py*

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import category, hire_article, localwork, salary,         mode_work, exp_year, degree, sex, language

class hire_articleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("hiring",)}
    list_display = ('id', 'hiring', 'publication_date', 'namecompany', )
    admin.site.register(hire_article, hire_articleAdmin)
```

It works only in admin . I want it to work in forms too.

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: Error is  slug field in forms  not working.

Comment: comment         fields = '__all__' and uncomment exclude = ['slug']

Comment: i tried but in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ slug is not auto add ^^

Answer (score 6):

Make the following change in your models.py and the change suggest in comments earlier in forms.py

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class hire_article(models.Model):
    hiring = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.hiring)
        super(hire_article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

ps: also your model naming convention is not recommended.Look at PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: DO you have skype or facebook? i really want to make friend with you.

Comment: It said ::"Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: I have a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712657/how-to-create-pagination-in-django

Comment: #Chirdeep Tomar plz help me.